# FileNotFoundException while copying db from assets to device data folder

Tags: android, sqlite, assets, filenotfoundexception, fileoutputstream

I tried in many ways to copy my sqlite db file to my /data/data/packagename/databases folder, but I still get stuck in FileNotFoundException, triggered by the FileOutputStream object...
Here's the code:

```
public static boolean checkCopyDb(Context c, DbHandler _db) {
    try {
        String destPath = "/data/data/" + c.getPackageName() + "/databases/db_sociallibraries.db";

        File dbFile = new File(destPath);

        if(!dbFile.exists()) {
            _db.copyDb(c.getAssets().open(DB_NAME), new FileOutputStream(destPath)); // Line 44 - Throws the exception
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

private void copyDb(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;

    while((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
    }

    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}
```

And this is the error:

> 02-09 01:28:46.384  24222-24222/com.test.michelemadeddu.sociallibraries W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.test.michelemadeddu.sociallibraries/databases/db_sociallibraries.db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>   02-09 01:28:46.384  24222-24222/com.test.michelemadeddu.sociallibraries W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
>   02-09 01:28:46.384  24222-24222/com.test.michelemadeddu.sociallibraries W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:88)
>   02-09 01:28:46.384  24222-24222/com.test.michelemadeddu.sociallibraries W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:128)
>   02-09 01:28:46.384  24222-24222/com.test.michelemadeddu.sociallibraries W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:117)
>   02-09 01:28:46.384  24222-24222/com.test.michelemadeddu.sociallibraries W/System.err﹕ at com.test.michelemadeddu.sociallibraries.DbHandler.checkCopyDb(DbHandler.java:44)

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Is 'c.getPackageName()' returning what you expect?

Comment: Yes @prudhvi, I also tried to write package name explicitly, but the result was the same. In fact if you look at the console message, it says that the error is in the FileOutPutStream, not the InputStream

Comment: What I'm assuming is, your file does not exist and so your 'if' condition is evaluating true. Check if you have the file in that path.

Comment: I can't @prudhvi, that folder is not accessible for browsing by device itself

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For compatibility, maybe you may change your internal db path to below

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
   DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";         
} else {
   DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code...
This is what i use and works fine.

Just replace the DB_NAME, DATABASE_NAME and DB_PATH variables.

```
package your.packagename;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data`/data/com.example.applicationame/databases/";`

// Database Name
private static String DB_NAME = "DB.sqlite";

// Logcat tag
private static final String LOG = "database";

// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB.sqlite";

// Table Names
private static final String TABLE_COUNTIES = "Counties";
private static final String TABLE_DESCRIPTIONS = "Descriptions";
private static final String TABLE_NEIGHBORHOODS = "Neighborhoods";

// Common column names
private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";

// TABLE_COUNTIES Table - column names
private static final String COL_COUNTYDETAIL = "countyDetail";
// TABLE_DESCRIPTIONS Table - column names
private static final String COL_DESCRIPTIONDETAIL = "descriptionDetail";
// TABLE_NEIGHBORHOODS Table - column names
private static final String COL_NEIGHBORHOODDETAIL = "neighborhoodDetail";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

private final Context myContext;

public static long INSERT_ERROR = -1;
/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */
public database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;

}   

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    Log.d(LOG, "Calling checkDataBase() Method");

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
        Log.d(LOG, "!!!Database Found!!!");
    }else{
        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        Log.d(LOG, "!!!Creating Empy Database!!!");
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
        try {
            Log.d(LOG, "!!!Coping Database!!!");
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    } 
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        Log.d(LOG, "looking database at " + myPath);

        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        //database does't exist yet.
        Log.e(LOG, "Exception: database does't exist yet");
    }

    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    Log.d(LOG, "Coping database from " + myInput + ", to " + outFileName);

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}


public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    openDataBase(true);
}

public void openDataBase(boolean readonly) throws SQLException{
    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    if (readonly)
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    else
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}    

}
```

I hope it helps.
Good Luck